# jsf seam and java cms

Tags: jsf, content-management-system, seam

Is there any good java cms compatible with jsf seam ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

[Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/). I haven't used it, but it's been around for a while.